# jax-rs sse client with Singleton in Glassfish/Payara

Tags: jax-rs, server-sent-events, java-ee-8

About jax-rs client with SSE in EJB Singleton, I've tried with Payara server full-5.183 (without docker) for this example, [https://abhirockzz.wordpress.com/2017/07/27/jax-rs-2-1-sse-client-api-example-using-glassfish-5-on-docker/], but failed. Error shown at line **eventSource = SseEventSource.target(target).build();**

```
 @PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.sseClient = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    this.target = this.sseClient.target("https://sse.now.sh");

    tsvc.createSingleActionTimer(15000, null);
    System.out.println("SSE client timer created");

    eventSource = SseEventSource.target(target).build();
    System.out.println("SSE Event source created........");
}
```

Error message: "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument fish.payara.requesttracing.jaxrs.client.decorators.JaxrsWebTargetDecorator@23112ded is not a valid JerseyWebTarget instance. SseEventSource does not support other WebTarget implementations."

Can anyone give me an idea?

Comment: Hey Peter, did you find a solution to his problem? I'm afraid I have the same problem...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55397191/wrong-webtarget-implementation-sseeventsource?
I would be very grateful if you would share your solution with me.